# How to mount a samba share permanently?

Tags: mount, 10.10, samba, sharing

How to mount a samba share permanently in Ubuntu 10.10? Also, I don't want to display the share icon on my desktop. How to achieve this task?

Answer (score 4):

If you ask about permanent mount, you should use configuraion via fstab.

Edit file `//etc/fstab` with root priviledges (for example `sudo leafpad //etc/fstab`)

and add a line which could look like this:

```
//<IPaddress>/<ShareName>   /<mountPoint>   cifs    user=<userName>,pass=<passwd> 0 0
```

You should use network drive username and password. Disadvantage is password written in a file. MountPoint should exist, (for example `/mnt/NetworkDrive`), create the folder before you reboot.

Save fstab and reboot. Done.

To ommit disadvantages, create .smbcredentials file

```
sudo leafpad /home/.smbcredentials
```

with following structure:

```
username=msusername
password=mspassword
```

and set

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/.smbcredentials
```

fstab line should be then as follows:

```
//<IPaddress>/<ShareName>   /<mountPoint>   cifs    rw,credentials=/home/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix, file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very detailed set of instructions on how to do this permanently from an Ubuntu point of view.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: I don't think the question involves windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should add it to /etc/fstab. I don't have a SMB server available at the moment but I think the fstab entry should look something like:

//server/share  /mountpoint smbfs

man fstab and man mount are your friends here.

Answer (score 0):

better choice than

```
mount -t smbfs //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o username=mywindowsusername,password=mywindowspassword
```

sould be

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o credentials=/root/.credMywindowsAccount
```

and in `/root/.credMyWindowsAccount`

```
username=mywindowsusername
password=mywindowspassword
```

Comment: it is not a permanent mount, after reboot mount is lost...