# Mounting Samba share whenever it's available, unmounting when it's not

Tags: mount, samba, automount, umount

I am trying setup permanent samba share mounts. That's not too hard using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently). But, I want them to

1. Automatically remount whenever I join the network where these shares are available.
2. Automatically unmount (or make access requests fail immediately instead of hanging) whenever I leave the network, i.e. avoid [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Server_is_down.2C_filesystem_is_hung) automatically.

Googling suggests that AutoFS might be helpful. I gather it takes care of the 1. above but I am not sure about the 2.

The other questions about automated Samba mounts, i.e. [How to mount a samba share permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34988/how-to-mount-a-samba-share-permanently), do not seem to address automatic remounts/unmounts, so I think this is not a duplicate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Mounting Samba shares with CIFS**:

Edit your `/etc/fstab` file to automatically mount your Samba shares:

```
//<server>/<share> <mount point> cifs rw,_netdev,user=<username>,password=<password>,uid=<uid>,gid=<gid> 0 0
```

Notice the **_netdev** option:

CIFS doesn't know about this option and will throw a warning about it, but you should leave it in.

This option ensures that the drives won't get mounted if you have no network or if you are on the wrong network.

It also makes sure your shares get mounted/unmounted when you switch networks. That's because Debian's if* scripts are triggered when your network configuration changes, and they watch all the filesystems with the **_netdev** option and do the right thing automagically.

[Source](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/07/automatically_mounting_and_unmounting_samba_windows_shares_with_cifs/)

you can check `man mount` for more information about **_netdev**

To install the CIFS tools

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. If this works as advertised, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome try and inform us by the result please

Comment: So what happens with you?!

Comment: I have planned to check this later today.

Comment: I added "//ip/share      /mnt/mnt-point    cifs    rw,_netdev,nodev,noexec,user,username=foo,password=bar,uid=foo,gid=foo,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700,nounix  0       0" to /etc/fstab, mounted the share, started a file op, killed the WiFi by HW switch, and it hanged.

Comment: ...actually it just has a rather big timeout value, but that's OK. I tested it some more, it does work. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day

Answer (score 4):

Write the scripts to mount and to unmount the share.

Place them in "/etc/network/if-up.d" and in "/etc/network/if-down.d" respectively. These are the locations for scripts that are run when the network connection is established or closed.

However, if you are looking for **a particular** server to come up or down online, the only solution I see is to make a *cron job* that checks the server connection periodically, keeps the state and runs the scripts accordingly.

Comment: For robustness (i.e. server going down unexpectedly) I think the latter solution is a better one. I will wait for more answers, if any, in the case this particular wheel has been invented already. Paldies.

Answer (score 1):

AutoFS will work fine. It will auto mount when you access the share, remount if dropped and unmount when idle. When you log off and your processes are all terminated (due to log off) then the mount will fall after being idle for some time. You can configure the idle time.

See this how-to: http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Will it hang trying to mount if I try to access the mount point outside the network? Likewise if it is mounted and I suspend while on the network, then resume outside of it with some request keeping the mount busy?

Answer (score 1):

The mount will always try to re-connect when you access the resource. If you are network hopping then it will depend if you have a route to the host or not. But, AutoFS will keep trying. There are parameters you can configure (timeouts, retries, etc).